# Injection vs. bijection between $V^\star \otimes V^\star$ and $(V \otimes V)^\star$

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, tensor-products, vector-spaces

It is a well-known fact that, if $V$ is a vector space over a field $k$, then $V^\star \otimes V^\star$ embeds into $(V \otimes V)^\star$.

It turns out to be an isomorphism when $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space.

**Why is this finite-dimensional restriction necessary?**

*More explicitly, where is the mistake in the following reasoning?*

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be (an infinite) basis of $V$. For all $b_0 \in \mathcal{B}$, we consider the map $b_0^\star : V \longrightarrow k$ defined for all $b \in \mathcal{B}$ by
$$ b_0^\star(b)
   =
   \left \{
      \begin{array}{ll}
           1 & \text{, if }b = b_0\\
           0 & \text{, otherwise}
      \end{array}
  \right.
$$
Consequently, $\mathcal{B}^\star = \{b^\star, b \in \mathcal{B}\}$ is a basis of $V^\star$. *(Does $\mathcal{B}^\star$ really span $V^\star$?)*

Similarly, we also consider for all $b_{01}, b_{02} \in \mathcal{B}$ the map $(b_{01} \otimes b_{02})^\star : V \otimes V \longrightarrow k$ defined for all $b_1, b_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ by
$$ (b_{01} \otimes b_{02})^\star(b_1 \otimes b_2)
   =
   \left \{
      \begin{array}{ll}
           1 & \text{, if }b_{01} = b_1 \text{ and } b_{02} = b_2\\
           0 & \text{, otherwise}
      \end{array}
  \right.
$$
Consequently, $\mathcal{C}^\star = \{(b_1 \otimes b_2)^\star, b_1, b_2 \in \mathcal{B}\}$ is a basis of $(V \otimes V)^\star$. *(Does $\mathcal{C}^\star$ really span $(V \otimes V)^\star$?)*

Consequently, the map $\varphi: V^\star \otimes V^\star \longmapsto (V \otimes V)^\star$ defined by $\varphi(b_1^\star \otimes b_2^\star) = (b_1 \otimes b_2)^\star$ for all $b_1, b_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ is well-defined and bijective, with an inverse bijection defined by $\varphi^{-1}\big ( (b_1 \otimes b_2)^\star \big ) = b_1^\star \otimes b_2^\star$.

**Finally, do we know an explicit example showing that $V^\star \otimes V^\star \hookrightarrow (V \otimes V)^\star$ is not an isomorphism when $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space?**

Comment: $B^*$ does not span $V^*$ if $V$ is infinite-dimensional, and similarly for $C^*$. As for an "explicit example", literally any infinite-dimensional $V$: formally, we can define an element of $(V\otimes V)^*$ which maps any element to the sum of coefficients in the expansion in the basis $b_1\otimes b_2$.

Comment: OK, nice (counter-)example! The problem comes from the fact that this element could not be spanned by a finite sum of $(b_1 \otimes b_2)^\star$...
Thank you Wojowu

Comment: Could we nevertheless construct a basis of $(V \otimes V)^\star$?

Comment: @NikWeaver You can identify the algebraic dual with the set of functions from $B$ into $k$, but how do you form a basis out of it?

Comment: I think the final question is not quite what you want to ask. It's likely that in many (all?) cases, the dimensions of $V^* \otimes V^*$ and $(V \otimes V)^*$ are the same, so they are abstractly isomorphic. That's not the interesting question; the interesting question is whether the natural map $V^* \otimes V^* \to (V \otimes V)^*$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn You're totaly right! That is my question. An answer should be constructed from Wojowu counter example

Comment: @NikWeaver What you said is not clear for me... Could you, please, explicit it?

Comment: @NikWeaver this is not a basis.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn When $V$ is of infinite dimension, the natural map is never an isomorphism, otherwise, the element constructed by Wojowu would have been in the image of $V^\star \otimes V^\star$ and would not have been a counter-example

Comment: Whereas when $V$ is of infinite dimension, the two sides are always abstractly isomorphic: if $\dim V$ is some infinite cardinal $\kappa$, then $V \otimes V$ has dimension $\kappa^2 = \kappa$, hence $V \cong V \otimes V$. Similarly, $V^* \otimes V^* \cong V^*$, so both sides are (very non-canonically) isomorphic to $V^*$.

Comment: This isn't really a research-level question. Dozens of variations have been asked and answered on MSE, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/679584/10014 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/573378/10014

Comment: One-to-one correspondence (as opposed to "one-to-one map") sounds like a bijection, so I'd rather rephrase the title as "Injection vs bijection..."

Answer (score 9):

Write $V=k^{(I)}$ (this is always the case, up to isomorphism, for some set $I$, namely take $I$ to be a basis subset).

So $V^*=K^I$, $V\otimes V=k^{(I\times I)}$ and the embedding of $V^I\otimes V^I$ into $V^{I\times I}$ in consideration maps $f\otimes g$ to $(f\otimes g)(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$.

I claim that the Kronecker function $(x,y)\mapsto\delta_{x,y}$ is not in the image.

Otherwise, we can write it as $(x,y)\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)g_i(y)$. We choose $n$ minimal (over all infinite $I$).

So $f_n\neq 0$. Fix $x_0$ with $f_n(x_0)\neq 0$. Then for all $y\neq 0$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_0)g_i(y)=0$. Hence on $I\smallsetminus\{x_0\}$ we have $g_n=-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(f_i(x_0)/f_n(x_0))g_i$. On $I'\times I'$ we rewrite the condition $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)g_i(y)=\delta_{x,y}$ by replacing $g_n$ with the above linear combination. Then we obtain a similar decomposition of $\delta_{\cdot,\cdot}$ with $n$ replaced with $n-1$. We thus contradict the minimality of $n$.